# Build output to CAB file VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, build, msbuild, cab

In VS 2010 there is an option to output a build to a cab file. I cant seem to find a way to do this in VS 2012. Does anyone know of a way? If I upgrade our VS 2010 project containing cabs to 2012 it doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an "extended" task. Not something built in (as far as I know).

http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.11.0/html/f7724cf2-0498-92d8-ba0f-26ca4772d8ee.htm

```
Cab Class
Members Example See Also Send Feedback
Valid TaskActions are:

AddFile (Required: NewFile, CabFile, CabExePath, ExtractExePath, NewFileDestination)

Create (Required: PathToCab or FilesToCab, CabFile, ExePath. Optional: PreservePaths, StripPrefixes, Recursive)

Extract (Required: CabFile, ExtractExePath, ExtractTo Optional: ExtractFile)

Compatible with:

Microsoft (R) Cabinet Tool (cabarc.exe) - Version 5.2.3790.0

Microsoft (R) CAB File Extract Utility (extrac32.exe)- Version 5.2.3790.0

Remote Execution Support: No

Namespace: MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression
Assembly: MSBuild.ExtensionPack (in MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll) Version: 3.5.0.0
```

There's an option.

Look as my answer to this post, and you can find a basic msbuild defintion (.proj file).

[How to setup building steps for CruiseControl.net from repository of the building project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404845/how-to-setup-building-steps-for-cruisecontrol-net-from-repository-of-the-buildin)